# verb for when you push on a bike's pedal

Tags: verbs

I'm not quite satisfied with the results Google Translate gave me, so I'd like to hear more from the community.

What's the action one does when pushing with his foot on a bike's pedal? Or more precisely, which verb would you use when building a sentence involving such action?
In Italian we have the rather straight-forward `pedalare`, which Google translates to `ride`, but that sounds a bit too generic in my opinion. 
(I think it's worth noting that, when inverting the words, `pedalare` is not among `to ride` translations)

So what do you think? Are there any other more specific verbs to use?

Comment: If the bicyclist is standing on the pedals and pressing them hard and quickly, the term _pumping_ is sometimes used (in U.S. English) to describe the action.

Comment: You could also ask this question in [Bicycles.SE](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/). They are the experts (friendly, too).

Comment: I always struggle with the lack of an English equivalent :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb would be to pedal, I believe. Perhaps to crank  would work as well.

Looking at the [Merriam-Webster definition of pedal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedal), we see it has a noun form as you already know:

> 2 :  a foot lever or treadle by which a part is activated in a mechanism

However, as we scroll down in the link, we find it also has an adjective and verb form, including:

> : to push the pedals of (something, such as a bicycle)
>
> : to ride a bicycle to a particular place

Comment: Yup. You could maybe [***strain against** the pedals*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22strain+against+the+pedals%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22strain+against+the+pedals%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.22606748j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if you *really* wanted to emphasise the effort, but as you say, the "unmarked" verb is just ***to pedal*** for all contexts. And ***to crank** [the pedals]* works fine for me to indicate that it's not *completely* "effortless" (which could be the case with the more generic verb).

Comment: duh, it was *that* simple then... well thanks for the input. I guess I won't be using gT as my primary source of translation from now on and, most of all, I will dig a bit deeper before asking. (as an unrelated sidenote, if such a question was to be posted on a few other `SE`s I won't mention, granted I'd have gotten a lot of hate for not researching a bit more before posting)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Peddling furiously seems to evoke  the right kind of picture in my mind's eye.

Comment: Also "push on the pedals": *When you are cycling, you need to push on the pedals to move forward*.

Comment: "Crank" would be unlikely to be used by bikers for this meaning, as it refers to the arm that the pedal is attached to.

Comment: English: *to pedal*. French: *pédaler*. Italian: *pedalare*. At least Google translate gets it right by way of French as an intermediary: E->I->F->E.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's fairly common to refer to a pedal *stroke*, when speaking of a single downward motion on the pedal.  (Eg, "With only three pedal strokes I was off and riding abreast of the others.")  But other terms are used as well.

[Mandatory web reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=jFctAQAAMAAJ&q=%22pedal+stroke%22&dq=%22pedal+stroke%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHm42l2bfPAhXM7SYKHcXeBroQ6AEIKjAD):

> If one is to believe the proponents of ankling, the rider should move
>   the toes of the foot down at the bottom of the pedal *stroke*.

Comment: I can't quite visualize a stroke of the pedal as it doesn't connote a complete 360 degree rotation but merely the downward motion as you state in your answer. Let's hear if for the upward motion, please!

Comment: @PeterPoint - You kinda get the upward motion for free, when you do a stroke on the other pedal.  The full circle is apt to be referred to as a "turn" or "rev"(olution).  (And, FWIW, the rate of circling is referred to as *cadence*.)

Comment: The downvote is kind of amusing, seeing as I have a 39K rep on the Bicycling SE.

Comment: Twas not I who cast the down vote! Evidently the scoundrel needs a stroke of the cane. Six of the best should do it. 39K - that's an impressive RPM